# bash script error for linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

this is the full code of my script which I use on linux RHEL5 and it used to have no error. Recently, I copied the same script file for use on another linux RHEL6 server and I get the following error:

```
[zenoss]$ bash zen-remote-bkp.sh
: command not foundline 14:
: command not foundline 23:
Started at :  Wed-11/05/14-@-09:42:13 AM-EST
: command not foundline 26:
find: `/opt/zenoss/backups/\r': No such file or directory
zen-remote-bkp.sh: line 51: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Code:

```
SERVER_HOSTNAME="server"
ZENOSS_BACKUP_DIR="/opt/zenoss/backups"
BACKUP_COUNT=0
RSYNC_HOST="client"
SSH_RSYNC_USER="zenoss"
SSH_RSYNC_DEST_DIR="/var/backups_dir/zenoss/$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
MESSAGE_FILE="/home/zenoss/message.txt"

# Initialize the message file with the starting date and time
echo "Started at : " `date +%a-%D-@-%X-%Z`

# Check to see if there are any backup archives
BACKUP_COUNT=`find $ZENOSS_BACKUP_DIR -name "zenbackup*" | wc -l`
if [ "$BACKUP_COUNT" -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "No backup archive to synchronize!"
        echo "Ended at : " `date +%a-%D-@-%X-%Z`
        exit 1
fi

# Transfer most recent backup via rsync over ssh and (later) delete all
# backups older than 3 days
RECENT_BACKUP=`ls -1 $ZENOSS_BACKUP_DIR/zen* | tail -n 1`
echo "Most recent backup : " $RECENT_BACKUP
rsync -az --stats --partial --ignore-existing -e ssh $RECENT_BACKUP $SSH_RSYNC_USER@$RSYNC_HOST:$SSH_RSYNC_DEST_DIR  2>&1
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "Backup archive replication failed!"
        echo "Ended at : " `date +%a-%D-@-%X-%Z`
        exit 1
fi

echo "Backup archive replication successful!"
echo "Ended at : " `date +%a-%D-@-%X-%Z`

exit 0
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of it? Thank you.

Comment: does your new system come with `[` ? Have you tried replacing it with `[[` ?

Comment: You can put `set -x` to debug your script. However the errors are pretty straight forward. "command not found" on line 14. What's on those lines?

Comment: I see a `\r` in there. When you copied from one to the other did you do it via Windows?

Comment: @arco444 has it. Run `dos2unix` on your script.

Comment: @glenn do we have a canonical question for this? I've seen it several times before and I'm sure you've seen it even more!

Comment: This is the first thing the tag info recommends checking before posting, but unfortunately this is not actually displayed on the screen where you post a question.

Comment: I retype all the same codes on a new created .sh on the new server instead of copying the script and it worked... weird but okay.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I also tried to used dos2unix and it worked well, thank you!